# How to pass more params to Winform control event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.8

I try to pass 3 extra int params to a button1_Click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int Xaxis, int Yaxis, int Zaxis)
    {
        switch (Xaxis)
        ...
        textBox1.Text = "Finished";
    }
...
```

To achieve ↓↓↓

```
...
public void Func1()
   {
      button1_Click(sender, e, 16, 5, 59)   //Pass 16 5 59 to event button1_Click
      //To perform a click event simulation with designated params
      ...
   }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        Func1();
    }
```

But there is something wrong with Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
//Compiler Error CS0123: No overload for 'method' matches delegate 'delegate'
```

How to pass 3 extra int params to a button1_Click event correctly?

Comment: If someone actually clicks the button, what values do you expect to be passed in your extra parameters when it invokes the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *extracting a method*, let's separate *business logic* ( `axis` routine) and *UI* (button click event handling):

```
private void MyClick(Button button, int Xaxis, int Yaxis, int Zaxis) {
  //TODO: All business logic here
  switch (Xaxis)
  ...
  textBox1.Text = "Finished";
}
```

Then use it

```
// Just UI event handler
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //TODO: put right axis values here
  MyClick(sender as Button, 0, 0, 0);
}

public void Func1()
{
  MyClick(button1, 16, 5, 59);   // Pass 16 5 59 
  //To perform a click event simulation with designated params
  ...
}

// Another UI event handler
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Func1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most generalized version of this answer that fully defines an event in the form called `AxisAction` and it is subscribed by different buttons in order to be triggered with specific arguments. The data itself is contained in a single `struct` called `Axis` in order to keep `{X,Y,Z}` together.

```
// Your data model
public readonly struct Axis
{
    public Axis(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Z = z;
    }

    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public int Z { get; }
}

// Your event arguments
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public MyEventArgs(Axis axis)
    {
        Axis = axis;
    }

    public Axis Axis { get; }
}

// Your event method
public delegate void AxisEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Your event
    public event AxisEventHandler AxisAction;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Subscribe to event
        AxisAction += Form1_AxisAction;
    }

    private void Form1_AxisAction(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the event here
        switch (e.Axis.X)
        {
            default:
                break;
        }
        // done!
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Trigger your event from the mouse click
        OnAxisAction(new MyEventArgs(new Axis(16, 5, 59)));
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Trigger your event from the mouse click
        OnAxisAction(new MyEventArgs(new Axis(-6, 2, 8)));
    }

    private void OnAxisAction(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Call any event handlers on event trigger
        AxisAction?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```